# Send all email data to a service from an outlook addin

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm new to office addins.  I'm an MVC programmer but this project has been dumped on me as no one else wants to do it.  I need to create an outlook addin that will forward all email data to a service where communications can be tracked by a recruitment system.
I am using

```
Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(saveEmail);
```

where I then cast the email into a Outlook.MailItem.  The problem is I see no way of getting the from and to email addresses.  All it gives me is the name of the people.  Am I missing something?

So far the best solution I can think of is to save the msg as a .msg file.  Forward that to my service and then user a parser I found to convert it to HTML.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the recipients, loop through MailItem.Recipients collection and access Recipient.Name and Recipient.Address properties.

Sender related properties are not yet set by the time ItemSend event fires - the earliest you can access sender properties is when Items.ItemAdd event fires on the Sent Items folder (retrieve it using Namespace.GetDefaultFolder).

You can read the MailItem.SendUsingAccount. If it is null, use the first Account from the Namespace.Acounts collection.  You can then use Account.Recipient object.

Keep in mind that you should not blindly cast outgoing items to MailItem objects - you can also have MeetingItem and TaskRequestItem objects.

Comment: Thanks, that works for the recipients but unfortunately it seems email is not always moved to the sent mail folder in outlook so the ItemAdd event on that was no help for me.  I will have to double check this when I'm back at work as I think there were differences when using exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

OK using the info given to me by Dmitry Streblechenko and some other info I just looked up here is my solution so far.

In the ItemSend event I first make sure that sent email is moved to the default sent items folder.  I'm testing outlook using gmail so normally these will go elsewhere.  sentMailItems is made as a class field as apparently it will get garbage collected if its just declared inside the Startup function (Something quite odd to me an MVC programmer :) ).

I' will test this on exchange when I get back to office an hopefully all goes well.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{

    public Outlook.Items sentMailItems;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(ItemSend);
        sentMailItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items;
        sentMailItems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Items_ItemAdd);
    }

    void Items_ItemAdd(object item)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((Outlook.MailItem)item).Subject);

        var msg = Item as Outlook.MailItem;


        string from = msg.SenderEmailAddress;

        string allRecip = "";
        foreach (Outlook.Recipient recip in msg.Recipients)
        {
            allRecip += "," + recip.Address;
        }
    }


    private void ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (!(Item is Outlook.MailItem))
            return;

        var msg = Item as Outlook.MailItem;

        msg.DeleteAfterSubmit = false; // force storage to sent items folder (ignore user options)
        Outlook.Folder sentFolder = this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) as Outlook.Folder;
        if (sentFolder != null)
            msg.SaveSentMessageFolder = sentFolder; // override the default sent items location
        msg.Save();            

    }
    //Other auto gen code here....
}
```